# Какая версия сайта отобразиться в данном случае

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пример, у меня телефон galaxy s 8 и на нем установлено разрешение экрана full hd ( 1920×1080). Я захожу на наш новый адаптивный сайт, и какую его версию я увижу? стандартную пк или адаптивную под мобайл. Десктоп версия начинается с 1260px. Сайт без мобильной версии, только адаптив

Comment: Зависит от того, сколько реальных пикселей занимает один CSS-пиксель в браузере, который вы используете на телефоне (это можно посмотреть через javascript в поле `window.devicePixelRatio`)

Comment: Если сайт правильно сверстан, то вы увидите адаптивную версию. Потому что правильно верстать в зависимости от ширины экрана устройства, а не от разрешения.